# variation of electrostatic potential on moving radially outwards from the nucleus of an atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrostatics, electrons, atomic-physics, potential

I was wondering how would the electrostatic potential change on moving radially outwards from the nucleus in an atom, considering the effect of the electron clouds around it.

Comment: @AcidJazz how would you calculate potential due to a electron cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The atom has some charge distribution $\rho(r)$. We don't don't know what form the function $\rho(r)$ has, but we do know it depends only on $r$ because an atom is spherically symmetric.

When you have a spherical charge distribution the potential at a distance $r$ is simply due to the total charge inside the distance $r$:

$$ V(r) = -\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{Q(r)}{r} \tag{1} $$

There is the positive charge due to the nucleus, which doesn't depend on $r$, and the negative charge due to the electron cloud is:

$$ Q_e(r) = \int_0^r \rho(R)4\pi R^2 dR \tag{2} $$

To calculate $V(r)$ you need to know the form of the charge distribution $\rho(r)$. For any atom with more than one electron there is no analytic formula for $\rho(r)$. We have to compute the charge distribution numerically, typically by doing a [Hartree-Fock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree%E2%80%93Fock_method) calculation. The HF calculation gives us $\rho(r)$, and we can then numerically integrate equation (2) to get $V(r)$.

Comment: Even though we dont know the exact charge distribution function, but is it possible to graph the potential function approximately ?

Comment: @Abhirikshma: I don't have electron density data to hand, but outside the atom the potential will be close to zero, in the outer reaches of the atom it will go as $1/r$ and near to the nucleus it will go as $Z/r$, where $Z$ is the nuclear charge. In between it will transition smoothly between those two limits.